# unity 3d backing does weird texture

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures

I have a model with 3 elements, each one has a different texture, when in real time everything looks awesome (both in designed and playing) but if I go and bake my lights I get the ugly mess you can see in the bottom part of the picture.

I'm pretty new to blender/unity. The game is aimed to android phones (google cardboard)

BAKED GI true

- Using: Blender 2.7
- Unity 5
- Backed resolution 1 (increasing doesnt help)
- Baked padding 2
- Compressed true
- Indirect Resolution 2
- Ambient occlusion 0

I don't even know what parameters are really helpful here. Can someone help?

[image: difference between RT and Backed]

Comment: You have to change some import settings of the mesh, but atm I can't remember which one.

Comment: please, if you manage to find it out let me know :) I'm surfing the options right now

Comment: I think checking `Generate Lightmap` was helping me.

Comment: GOD, it fixes it. If you would like to just add your comment as an answer I will gladly accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting `Generate Lightmap` in the [importsettings](http://docs.unity3d.com/401/Documentation/Components/FBXImporter-Model.html) should solve the problem.